# Admin form action to another admin controller can not reach

Tags: magento2, admin, forms, adminform, admin-controller

In Magento2, I create a form by phtml file in admin, but when I submit it, it always redirect to admin homepage, **not reach** another admin controller, how to fix it?

I guess the problem is in the **action url**, but I don't have a idea to fix it.

### form codes

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('migration/index/post') ?>" method="post" style="text-align: center;">
    <label for="sku">Sku: </label>
    <input type="text" name="sku" id="sku" size="40">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: can u share your controller & etc\adminhtml\routes.xml file code in question?

Comment: Add form_key field in your form.phtml file: code is:

    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey() ?>" /

Comment: @Abdul Thanks, you are right, I forget form_key, but your codes don't work, I will add the working codes in the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abdul's comment is right, I forget the **form_key**, but simply use `$block->getFormKey()` will not generate the form_key in phtml file. We need **create the method** in our block.

### What is form_key

**Form keys** in Magento are a means of preventing against **Cross Site Request Forgery**, it instructs Magento to output and store a unique form key for a user session. All CSRF-protected Magento controller actions will verify against this before doing anything of value.

### Create the getFormKey() in our block

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Form extends Template
{
    protected $_backendUrl;

    protected $formKey;

    /**
     * Form constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     * @param FormKey $formKey
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        FormKey $formKey
    )
    {
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormKey()
    {
        return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
    }
}
```

### Form Codes

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('migration/index/post') ?>" method="post" style="text-align: center;">
    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey() ?>">
    <label for="sku">Sku: </label>
    <input type="text" name="sku" id="sku" size="40">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```